# Error for install APK in android programming

Tags: android, developer-tools

there was a problem parsing the package
I could not this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvf5R.png) problem

Comment: Add your app.gradle file content.

Answer (score 0):

Do clean you project and build it again. Then, In the Android menu, go to Build > Build Bundle(s) / APK (s) > Build APK(s).
Try to install created build.